# Streamlit display generated images with download button in form

Tags: python, streamlit

Hi I have a usecase where I have a streamlit form where I let user to upload images and based on the input images I generate multiple images. I write these images to tmp directory and wants to show it on the page along with a download button.

Now my challenge is when I call `show_image()` after `generate` it throws the error that download button is not allowed in form.
And when I call `show_image` after `main` it gets executed as soon as the form loads before even the images are generated.

How can I add the show image and download option after the execution of `generate` method?

Error:

```
StreamlitAPIException: st.download_button() can't be used in an st.form().

For more information, refer to the documentation for forms.

Traceback:
File "/Users/anup.rawka/Documents/GitHub/vdil-ai-framework/creative_automation/app/scripts/creative_app.py", line 65, in <module>
    main()
File "/Users/anup.rawka/Documents/GitHub/vdil-ai-framework/creative_automation/app/scripts/creative_app.py", line 62, in main
    show_image()
File "/Users/anup.rawka/Documents/GitHub/vdil-ai-framework/creative_automation/app/scripts/creative_app.py", line 35, in show_image
    st.download_button(
```

```
def show_image():
    for i in range(1, 7):
        img = Image.open(r"{}{}.png".format(base_path, i))
        buf = BytesIO()
        img.save(buf, format="PNG")
        byte_im = buf.getvalue()
        st.image(img)
        st.download_button(
            label="Download image", data=byte_im,
            file_name="{}.png".format(i), mime="image/png")


def main():
    st.image('../images/1st_screen_masthead_3up_1824_412.png', caption='3up 1st Screen Masthead Template 1824x412')
    # side_bar, work_area = st.columns([0.2, 0.8])
    setup_sidebar()
    with st.form("US STVP 2Program 1stScreenMasthead 1824x412"):
        img_tpfm_shw_1 = st.file_uploader("Choose show 1 image")
        img_tpfm_shw_1_logo = st.file_uploader("Choose show 1 logo")
        img_tpfm_shw_2 = st.file_uploader("Choose show 2 image")
        img_tpfm_shw_2_logo = st.file_uploader("Choose show 2 logo")
        img_tpfm_shw_3 = st.file_uploader("Choose show 3 image")
        img_tpfm_shw_3_logo = st.file_uploader("Choose show 3 logo")
        submit_button = st.form_submit_button('Generate Creative')
        if submit_button:
            img_shw1 = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_1)
            img_shw2 = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_2)
            img_shw1_logo = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_1_logo)
            img_shw2_logo = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_2_logo)
            img_shw3 = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_3)
            img_shw3_logo = iio.imread(img_tpfm_shw_3_logo)
            generate(img_shw1, img_shw1_logo, img_shw2,
                     img_shw2_logo, img_shw3,
                     img_shw3_logo)


main()
show_image()
```